# Call vue method from inside kendo-ui grid col template

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

I am trying to call a component method from inside a Kendo-UI grid column template, but I am getting a reference error. The problem is I have some global text formatting functions that I would like to share as a mixin. Is there anyway to call a vue component method from inside a grid col template?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <kendo-datasource ref="emailAccountDS"
                    :transport-read-url="'api/EmailAccounts'"
                    :transport-read-data-type="'json'"
                    :transport-read-type="'get'"
                    :type="'aspnetmvc-ajax'"
                    :schema-data="'data'"
                    :schema-total="schemaTotal"
                    :schema-model-id="'id'"
                    :schema-model-fields="schemaModelFields"
                    :server-paging= "true"
                    :server-sorting="true"
                    :server-filtering="true"
                    :page-size="25"
                    >
        </kendo-datasource>
        <kendo-grid :data-source-ref="'emailAccountDS'"
                    :pageable-always-visible="false"
                    :pageable-refresh="true"
                    :selectable="'row'"
                    :sortable="true"
                    :filterable="true"
                    :auto-bind="true"
                    :editable="'popup'"
                    :toolbar="['create','edit']">
            <kendo-grid-column field="hostName" title="Host Name"></kendo-grid-column>
            <!-- ReferenceError: testMethod is not defined --> 
            <kendo-grid-column field="accountType" title="Account Type" template="# testMethod(accountType) #"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="port" ></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="useSsl"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="username"></kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'EmailAccounts',
        data: function () {
            return {
                schemaModelFields: {
                    id: { type: 'number', editable: false, nullable: true },
                    isEnabled: { type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true, validation: { required: true } },
                    hostName: { type: 'string', validation: { required: true } },
                    port: { type: 'number', defaultValue: 995, validation: { required: true } },
                    useSsl: { type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true, validation: { required: true } },
                    username: { type: 'string', validation: { required: true } }
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            testMethod(accountType) {//<=== ReferenceError: testMethod is not defined
                return "foo";
            },
            schemaTotal: function (response) {
                return response.total;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

I have setup a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/PijtVAXnNVCb2oOFnsED) that shows the same error.

I found [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/access-created-method-vuejs-in-kendo-grid) thread that said this should be working since 2018.1. This is version of kendo-ui I am running.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@progress/kendo-datasource-vue-wrapper": "^2018.2.516",
    "@progress/kendo-grid-vue-wrapper": "^2018.2.516",
    "@progress/kendo-layout-vue-wrapper": "^2018.2.516",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.53.1",
    "@progress/kendo-treeview-vue-wrapper": "^2018.2.516",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2018.2.516",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.3.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-awesome": "^2.3.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.2"
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that kendo template (with "# something #") "compiles" inside kendo code and there is no reference to your Vue app.
But in jquery-kendo docs I found that you can pass function to template. As I can see in kendo source code template function always should return not null/undefined value. So I added changes below and it works like a charm:

1. Changes in Vue template(bind template attr to function) `<kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="Units In Stock" :template="isInStock" :width="120"></kendo-grid-column>`
2. Changes in Vue component code (slightly changed `isInStock` method to expect current data item object as in docs and made it always returns value):

   ```
   isInStock: function(dataItem){ 
     if(dataItem.UnitsInStock < 0 || !dataItem.UnitsInStock){
        return "Out of stock";
       }
       return dataItem.UnitsInStock; 
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a general solution that I can reuse on multiple grids.

Comment: @Padhraic what's a problem to reuse this solution? This is general solution how to output dynamic value based on data item field (using Vue component method) according to docs.

Comment: The isInStock function will fail if the model does not have UnitsInStock field. I was hoping for a solution that I could reuse on any number field.

Comment: In my example `isInStock` function will return "Out of stock" string if field does not exist in object. If you want to declare **field name** in markup so you can wrap function with another, see [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bx5RP8K6UBISnZP8KJuy)